# Magento 1.9 Product page customization

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, xml

I'm using Magento 1.9.3 to make my store, but I came to a custom layout problem right now.
I tryed by my own looking in similar topics over there but couldn't figure it out.

I need to put my custom attributes in different places instead of tabs.

I have the "Informação Adicional" (en_US: Additional Info [attributes]) that I need in the right column.

Thanks!

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried what @MauroNigrele suggested, but without success. So I tried to copy the php instructions from *frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml* into a block I use in the right column, as you may guess, not worked (I'm a newbie).

Now I thought on doing something that may be easier.
Create a new block that I could use in the right column, showing the "Aditional Info" tab, instead of a collateral tab, where it is right now.

So, it should show me the Aditional Info where previously I wanted to show only the tracklist.

I supposed it may have something to do with this kind of code:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="tracklist" template="frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml"}}
```

But I still couldn't figure it out how to do that, I readed other topics with something similar, but I couldn't understand them clearly.

They are as follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710077/calling-an-attribute-in-a-cms-block-in-magento?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883139/how-to-add-product-attribute-on-product-page-via-cms-block-magento

Shortly, I want to put the "Informação Adicional" (Additional Info) in the right column. As I saw, their php file is from:
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

It may be useful to say I use a custom theme: Ultimo.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to work with the default and rwd catalog.xml, moving the additional block into the right column, but it doesn't show in the website.

**UPDATE 3**

I did what @ Ahmed El Awadi saidin local.xml, and now it shows in the right column:
*There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.*
The code used is:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
```

**UPDATED with new description image**

Comment: did you try to edit your xml instead of working with phtml files

Comment: In Xml find block  name="product.attributes" and move it <reference name="right">

Comment: in Ultimo >> local.xml link 551 this is attribute table call. cop this to line 487 under <reference name="right">

Comment: I tryed over webftp, without success, I'll download the file and open with Dreamweaver to copy the right line. Will update asap.

Comment: it will work if you are using 2-columns-right.phtml template

Comment: I did, and now it shows in the right column: There was no 404 CMS page configured or found. The code: <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>

Comment: @AhmedElAwadi any hints in what I missed?

Comment: I will test in my local today and update you shortly

Answer (score 2):

You can use the exactly same approach that is used for "Fabricante" You just need to change the attribute code for the new one, in the right template ie:

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/templates/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<div class="product-sarasa">
    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSarasa(), 'sarasa') ?>
</div>
```

To find the right template file just activate "template hints" in:

> System > Configuration > Advanced - Developer > Debug > Template Path Hints.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it may have been misunderstood. The "Fabricante" is what I wrote in the short_description when I add the product. I tryed looking into the files, but all I could find out is that the block name is _italic_ Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes _italic_ and that those that I want to modify, doesn't have a specific name, at least not in the frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml as I added them as new attributes. I'm still searching for some documentation or another topics who could help me. I think is a hard coding question :/

Comment: Even if I show the complete Maage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes in the right column will be fine too. Maybe copying the .phtml code into the block displayed in the right column? I'll try

Comment: I copied the php code into the block I'm using in the right column, it didn't work ou

Comment: @whiteisred90 Every product attribute type must be printed in a different way I used `Fabricante` as a reference. So if you want to echo a text attribute the technique it's a bit different as used for a select or multi-select one. Would be nice to see what have you already tried, please update the question with the actual code.

Comment: any hints in what I missed?